# Looking for an extremely compact USB-C WiFi adapter

Tags: usb, wifi

I am looking for a USB-based WiFi adapter which should be extremely compact, that is not much bigger than the USB-C connector it's based on.

It needn't be able to reach more than 2-3 meters with reasonable bandwidth, though.

I've seen fairly compact USB-A WiFi adapters, but so far none with USB-C.

NB: please consider that there have been memory cards with built-in WiFi (e.g. search `Wi-Fi SD card`), so the size of the respective chips surely shouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I struggled to find any USB-C Wi-Fi adapters currently on the market, and if any do exist, I imagine they won't be the form factor that you are looking for.

Comment: It's still hard to find any - the best solution right now would be to use a nano USB-A WiFi dongle together with an USB-C to USB-A adapter (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adapter-Aluminum-Supports-Transmission-Suitable/dp/B09957M3JG/ref=sr_1_9)